# Початкові голосні

Tags: фонетика, історія-мови

При проглядѣ нп. словника можна помѣтити або подумати, що українська майже — лише малочисельні винятки — не має питомих слів, що починають ся з голосноѣ. Можна навѣть натрапити на [твердєння](//promovu.in.ua/adopted-words/) такого роду: *тільки іншомовні слова мають на початку слова літеру **а***. Винятком хиба що є голосні **о** і **у**, де для другого можна також списати на вплив відповѣдного приростка і евфонії. Пак навѣть до того ж **о** можуть додавати ся [протези](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0), як в *горѣх*, *вона* ітд. Може навѣть також скласти ся враження, що гісторічно склади починали ся лише з приголосного.

Схоже, це радше загальнословянська проблема, що може здати ся дещо дивним, бо нп. ґрецька, нѣмецька, італійська ітд, що теж є мовами індоевропськоѣ родини, досить насичені такими словами. Тож, які фонолоґічні не/змѣни повпливали на таку особївість мови?

Comment: Цікаве запитання. Я навіть думаю, що його варто ставити на [linguistics.se], а не тут. Думаю, починати треба з [цієї статті на Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F), а далі залежно від бажаної глибини відповіді.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine Так, на Лінґвістікс можна продублувати.